# Type casting in VBA using SQL in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, casting, type-conversion

I need to convert all the records of a NON-Unicode table into a Unicode table by using something like the CAST function in SQL Server which looks like this:

```
Cast ([Transaction_No] as [nvarchar](14))
```

But now I'm using MS Access so can I do a type casting in the VBA code? 
Or is there another work around that could solve this problem for me?

In my table t_Transaction I have this field:
TRANSACTION_NO, defined as

```
DateType=Text, FieldSize=50
```

And what I want it to be:

```
DateType=Number, FieldSize=Integer
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code to demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ok, tried to do so. All the fields in my table t_Transaction are defined as DateType=Text, FieldSize=50, and I would like to CAST them to other fieldtypes, fx Integers, Date etc.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results, including data types, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string values are all valid integers you can use:

```
CInt(YourStringValue)
```

There are various other converstion functions along these lines (CBool(), CStr() etc).

You can even avoid this entirely as you should be able to implicitly convert them in VBA:

```
YourIntegerVariable = YourStringValue
```

Comment: All the values are in NON-Unicode format, since they are imported from a csv-file. So seems like I cannot make CInt(YourStringValue) work.

Comment: What error do you get? ASCII should work fine. Once again, please post your code.

Comment: Yes, and tell us what you are doing. Are you doing an import, are you executing a query, are you doing something with VBA, have you linked a CSV as table or what?

Answer (score 0):

In Access everything is treated as Unicode. You will not have to make any casts from non-Unicode to Unicode.